# What is the most "data.table" way to assign values to a column of a data.table from a different data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to assign the values from column "True_value" in data.table b into the column of the same name in data.table a. I finally did get something to work, but I'm not sure 1)why it worked and 2)whether there's a better way. Any insight would be appreciated. And yes, with respect, I have read up on data.table a little.

```
require(data.table)
a=as.matrix(c("a","b","c"))
a=cbind(a,c("yes", "no", "maybe"))
a=cbind(a,c("NA","NA","NA"))
rownames(a)=c("one", "two","three")
colnames(a)=c("letter", "status", "True_value")

a=as.data.table(a)

b=as.data.table(c(3,13,42))
colnames(b)=c("True_value")

a[,True_value]
b[,True_value]

##this doesn't work
a[,True_value] = b[,True_value]

##this doesn't assign the values, but rather assigns the string, "True_value"
a[,"True_value"] = b[,"True_value"]

##this doesn't work
a[,.(True_value)] = b[,.(True_value)]

##none of these work

a[,.(True_value)] = unlist(b[,True_value])
a[,True_value] = unlist(b[,True_value])

##and yet this one works. Why does this work, and is there a better way to do this?
a[,"True_value"] = unlist(b[,True_value])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is a really amazing way of creating a data.table :)

```
require(data.table)

a <- data.table(letter = c("a","b","c"),
                status = c("yes", "no", "maybe"),
                True_value = NA_real_)

b <- data.table(True_value = c(3, 13, 42))

# I am not sure if this is the most "data.table" way of doing this,
# but it is readable at least:
a[, True_value := b[, True_value]]
```

#### If you want to match any number of columns in any order:

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)

a <- data.table(V1 = c("a","b","c"),
                V2 = c("yes", "no", "maybe"),
                V3 = NA,
                V4 = NA)

b <- data.table(V4 = c(1, 2, 3),
                ignore = c(99),
                V3 = c(3, 13, 42))

# Get positions of matching columns in a,
# thanks to match can be in any order
fromA <- match(names(b), names(a)) %>% na.omit()

# Get positions of matching columns in b in the original order
fromB <- which(names(b) %in% names(a))

a[, fromA, with = FALSE]

b[, fromB, with = FALSE]

a[, fromA := 
    b[, fromB, with = FALSE],
  with = FALSE]

print(a)
```

Comment: And, if `b` has a `letter` column too it can be used to *join* on, and only update specific rows: `a[ b, on=c("letter"), True_value := i.True_value]`

Comment: @Atticus29 - is that question for me? In the [next version of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) the `on=.( letter )` syntax will be available (so you don't need the quotes).

Comment: @Atticus29, and you succeeded! Check my edit, could be useful.

Comment: @Atticus29, please go through http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf, it will be very helpful in this case, esp. section 1.

Comment: @M.D. That link is out of date (October 2014). The project moved to github, with the faq here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Someone has to notify Google about that (I've just googled for "data.table faq" and pasted 1st link, apologies). BTW, @Frank, there is not much under the link you posted...

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. I'm asking them about it. In the meantime, I somehow came across this (April 2016): https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html